# How to check which distribution certificate signed an .ipa?

Tags: ios, certificate, enterprise, account

I have 2 distribution certificates in my enterprise account, and I have distributed a app with one of the certificates of this account, but I don't know which certificate I signed with.

Now the private keys associated with both certificates have been lost. I have to use a new certificate to sign the app when I distribute a new version next time, but one enterprise account can only generate 2 distribution certificates at most, so I have to revoke a distribution certificate, but I don't know which one can be revoked, if I revoke the certificate that has used to sign my app last time, then all the apps have installed on the user's phone will can't be open.

what should I do? Thank you very much.

Comment: in general check Singing release. Your certificate that is associate with the project will be shown.

Comment: Could you tell me where to check the Singing release ? I don't know much about this. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hope below image will help you,

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I choosed  the Automatically manage signing, so I can't see the "Signing Certificate".

Comment: @NineCity You need to uncheck it. Then select release option and see if it automatically showing any eligible certificate. If yes, thats what you are searching for, if not then you need to work on probability .

Comment: There seems to be no eligible certificate, but thank you all the same.@dahiya_boy